# inserting quotes in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I can easily upload a file delimited by ^ 
It looks something like...

CN^others^2012-05-03 00:02:25^^^^^Mozilla/5.0^generic web browser^^^^^^^^

CN^others^2012-05-03 00:02:26^^^^^Mozilla/5.0^generic web browser^^^^^^^^

But if I have a double quote somewhere, it fails with an error message...

Line:1 / Field:, Data between close double quote (") and field separator: field starts with: 
Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.

CN^others^2012-05-03 00:02:25^^^^^"Mozilla/5.0^generic web browser^^^^^^^^

I do regulary get the files with "Mozilla as browser name, how do I insert data with double quotes?

Comment: sed 's/\"//'  # using sed I have removed double quotes, but I will like to know how to I handle quotes while inserting data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes can be escaped with another quote. For example, the field: `This field has "internal quotes".` would become `This field has ""internal quotes"".`

`sed 's/\"/\"\"/g'` should do the trick.

Note that in order to import data that contains quoted newlines, you need to set the allow_quoted_newlines flag to true on the import configuration. This means the import cannot be processed in parallel, and so may be slower than importing data without that flag set.

Comment: I get the file from third party in gzip format and I do not get an opportunity to execute the sed command. I will like to know if there can be a parameter that will allow quotes when the delimiter is something like '^' or pipe '|'. In such cases double quotes need not be escaped.

Comment: I've filed an internal feature request to allow specification of arbitrary (or no) quote chars. I think this would be clearer than trying to determine how quote behave based on the delimiter.